# php - intersect multidemsional arrays with one same value

Tags: php

I have array1 like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => test
        [1] => 123
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => testx
        [1] => 456
    )

)
```

and array2 like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => test
        [1] => somenumber
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => title
        [1] => sometitle
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => testx
        [1] => othernumber
    )

 )
```

I need output like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => test
        [1] => 123
        [2] => somenumber
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => testx
        [1] => 456
        [1] => othernumber
    )

)
```

So I need to compare only value with [0]key of each array. I have tried combinations with array_intersect and array_diff but I just can't get it to work. Can anybody please point me in some direction, what is proper function/way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with some instructions :)

```
<?php

$array1[] = ['test',  '123'];
$array1[] = ['testx', '456'];

$array2[] = ['test', 'a'];
$array2[] = ['testx', 'b'];
$array2[] = ['other', 'c'];

$indexColumns = array_column($array1, 0);
// We extact an array of key/values for column 0
// = [0 => test, 1 => testx]

foreach( $array2 as $key => $value ) {
  // If we can find the value of the first column on the indexColumn
  if( ($foundKey = array_search($value[0], $indexColumns)) !== false ) {
    unset($value[0]);
    $array1[$foundKey] = array_merge($array1[$foundKey], $value);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'test' (length=4)
      1 => string '123' (length=3)
      2 => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'testx' (length=5)
      1 => string '456' (length=3)
      2 => string 'b' (length=1)
```